# Bing Spell Check API - ignoring Gibberish

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Its seems like **Bing Spell Check API** does not work as I excepted.
A lot of mistakes are ignored...

For example:
"lets go to the see and then to gfgdf." response: "flaggedTokens": []
"lets blhblh to the sea" response: "flaggedTokens": []
Where: "lets go to the see" response:

```
{
  "flaggedTokens": [
    {
     ...
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "let's",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     ...
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "sea",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_type": "SpellCheck"
}
```

Can I do something to get more reliable results?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's worst on my side...
I always got the same result:

```
{
 "_type": "SpellCheck",
 "flaggedTokens": []
}
```

If somebody happens to kown how to prevent that I would like to know.

I guess that's maybe about migrating to Azure. Maybe thoses endpoints are not functionning correctly now.